# How do you find the corresponding value of the top item in a list with variable length?

Tags: database, excel, formula, vlookup

I need to find the value corresponding with the first item in a list.
For example, below is a database with item name and it's value.

[image: Database]

And further below is an invoice with items purchased. Cell C4 needs to bring up the first item's value only i.e. 101 for item2. Each invoice can have any number of items and I need the value only from the top item.

[image: Invoice]

Below is what I'd like the result to finally look like.
I'm able to use VLOOKUP to find the last value in each list but because the length of each invoice list varies it's difficult to create a formula that finds the first that doesn't become overly complicated.

[image]

Please let me know if there is any details I can add to help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in C1 and copy down, (you will need to change the reference to match your data set):

```
=IF(B1="Value",INDEX($I$1:$I$3,IFERROR(MATCH(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$1:INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1))/($B$1:INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1)="Value"),1)+1),$H$1:$H$3,0),1)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scott beat me to it but:

In C1

```
=IF(B1="Value",
    VLOOKUP(OFFSET(A$1,LARGE((B$1:B1="Value")*ROW(B$1:B1),2),0),
            $I$1:$J$20,2,FALSE),
    "")
```

Where $I$1:$J$20 has your lookup table